# Ipad and Iphone: Javascript image input buttons (radio, checkbox) not working well

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

We are using a website with some forms that have Javascript layover images over its radio buttons and checkboxes. These work well on IE7 upwards and Firefox, Safari etc. on Windows and Mac. The images layover the radio buttons/checkboxes using special javascript from Prototype and a plugin called "Protocheck" which we downloaded back in 2008 to implement on the site.

The problem is, our client has just reported:
"A customer has contacted us trying to order on an ipad, he is unable to select a source code (radio option) on his ipad and cant get past the page because of this."
"Also i attempted a transaction on my iphone - i selected a foot size but then it would not let me select a calf width and therefore could not complete the sale"

As an example see:
http://www.duoboots.com/products/bo...-taupe_leather/
(please see select your size and select your calf width radio buttons)

Questions, help needed:

1. We are downloading simulators to try (Phonegap to start for the Iphone) but can I just check if anyone knows about this issue or has experienced this before?
2. Does anybody know of any methods to simulate ipad and iphone on my pc or Mac? Or any good applications for that?(since i do not have an ipod or ipad) --- especially ipad since I've not heard any solid recommendations for simulators yet

Thanks in advance,
Isuru

Answer (score 1):

You can download Xcode, which comes with an iPhone and iPad simulator. You could then run the simulator and load your website in Safari on either of the devices to test your customer issues.

Xcode Download:

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html

Comment: Hi all, I have found the solution for this. Posting so everyone will know. In Iphone and I pad you will need to have an "OnClick" event even if you do not need one. Because otherwise if you are using something like I have described above (protocheck) it will not take that elemet as a clickeble one. So solutin is having a fake "OnClick" so I pod & Pad detects it as a click able element. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this. Posting so everyone will know. In Iphone and I pad you will need to have an "OnClick" event even if you do not need one. Because otherwise if you are using something like I have described above (protocheck) it will not take that elemet as a clickeble one. So solutin is having a fake "OnClick" so I pod & Pad detects it as a click able element. :)